# Удаление после знака

Tags: php

Как правильно удалить сам знак и текст который стоит после него?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам, заюзал explode()

```
$text = "ололол точика, а тут текста короч";
$text = explode(',',$text);
echo $text[0]; // выведет "ололол точика"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "ололол точика, а тут текста короч";
text = text.split(',')[0];
```

Comment: а через php не как? просто я редактирую данные переданные через _GET. А такой способ заставит меня: заводить в скрытый input параметры get, там все делать, потом через php+ajax читать уже полученные данные.

Это костыль я считаю.